# Как использовать API Яндекс Переводчика в скрипте?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, яндекс-переводчик

На сайте Яндекса получил [API](https://tech.yandex.ru/translate/). Инструкцию прочитал, ничего не понял.

Тут вот такая функция:

```
https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/getLangs ? 
key=<API-ключ>
 & [ui=<код языка>]
 & [callback=<имя callback-функции>]
```

Который, мне не известно.

Как использовать API Яндекс.Переводчика на обычном сайте с помощью обычного скрипта или jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Приветствую

Пример использования

```
var url = 'https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/getLangs?key=trnsl.1.1.20160325T130025Z.a7384fd1c9198dd9.a93fe8c8077b1400a27&ui=ru';
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
   data; // что то делаем с ответом в случае если все успешно
});
```

Comment: можно по подробнее? а то я не очень в скриптах, вот допустим API KEY от Яндекса **trnsl.1.1.20160325T130025Z.a7384fd1c9198dd9.a93fe8c8077b1400a27**  здесь куда ставить это кей `var url = 'https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/getLangs?...';
$.get(url, function(data) {
   data; // что то делаем с ответом в случае если все успешно
});` и как указать default язык сайта? потом как заставить для перевода на нужный язык

Comment: Подправил ответ

Comment: язык указан в самом конце значения url

Comment: как вы поправили получил вот такой [ответь] (https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/getLangs?key=trnsl.1.1.20160325T130025Z.a7384fd1c9198dd9.a93fe8c8077b1400a27f437787b11865ab13109a&ui=ru)

Comment: поздравляю, все правильно работает

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! но что делать далее... как получит кнопки для выбора перевода ?

Comment: А задача какая стоит?

Comment: задача будет такая! сайт на Азербайджанском , будет кнопки для выбора с az-ru az-en и так далее ...

Comment: Тогда следующий этап - сделать html код кнопки. Когда это будет готово, то эту кнопку надо будет заполнить полученными языками из написанного в ответе кода. И после обрабатывать нажатие кнопки - делать перевод.

Comment: А чем не устраивает [виджет от яндекса](https://translate.yandex.ru/developers/website-widget) ?

Comment: пример можно как это сделать ? кнопки то сделаю не проблема а заполнит полученными кодом как?

Comment: Проще написать код скрипта после того как будет известен код кнопки.

Comment: пример вот  несколько `<ul id="test-api-key"><li>Русский</li><li>Азербайджанский</li><li>Английский</li></ul>`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37525/discussion-between-maxim-bogdanov-and-samir-mamedov).